# Change Grouped UITableViewCell curve angle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was wondering what is the best way to change the radius that the corners are rounded in a `UITableViewCell` (grouped).

I tried to accomplish this using the `setCornerRadius` and `setMaskToBounds` methods as seen in another post, but it seems that I cannot reduce the degree that each cell curves past a certain threshold.  (If I set `setCornerRadius` to zero, the corners are still round).

I'm new to this so I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the number of rows and the row content in the table view static or dynamic?

Comment: The rows and content are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom cells with bespoke images for the cell backgrounds (or sub views with rounded corners if you prefer). There is a good guide [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) which describes the structure of table view cells and how you manage the background for each cell.

Comment: That guide is quite old and there have been a lot of changes with the way you can prototype cells in table. While it might provide you with a answer, it will not be the best, fastest or easiest answer.

Comment: @DBD I've expanded the answer. I know the guide is old but I don't think prototypes offer a lot of benefit for this particular case. Do you have a reference to show how they do?

Comment: I do not have a better example or I would have provided it. Prototypes will let you layout almost everything about the cell in visual and straight forward way. Setting `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` will still need to be done in code, but the rest of the code can all be done in IB. Back in 2009 you'd need to do this in a XIB file and load up XIB and attach it all which was often just more effort than writing the code, but now prototypes/IB will do almost all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fairly new and don't want to get deep into custom UITableViewCell (it's a bit of a pain with what you're trying to do, since you have to keep track of the cell position, whether it's a top, middle, or bottom cell and assign a custom background image to give it a fake 'grouped' effect while allowing you to customize the corner radius).

An easy library to use is PrettyKit (https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit) but watch out for the shadows, etc - the cells can get slow if you've got a lot of complex content. For simple table views it should be sufficient though.  We can get into custom cells if you think PrettyKit's performance doesn't meet your needs, let me know.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a shot.  I think the PrettyKit is more my level.